# Mysql + date comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause

I am using `mysql` as DB for my project. I have a table as follows:

**tableA**

```
start_date   end_date
2017-04-01   2017-04-31
```

I am getting input from user as `start` and `end`

I want to get the data which is greater `>=` start and `within` the end. I tried the following query

`SELECT * FROM aaa WHERE (start_date >= '2017-04-01' AND end_date <= '2017-04-07');`

But it returns `empty set` because `2017-04-31` is not `<=` 2017-04-07. So I want to return if user entered end date is also within the end_date range.

Comment: The table contains date ranges and the user provides a data range. Do you want the user's date range completely within the table's date range? Or does it suffice the two date ranges overlap? If the user provides `2020-02-01 - 2020-02-10`, which of the following rages do you consider a match: `2020-02-05 - 2020-02-06`, `2020-01-20 - 2020-02-06`, `2020-02-05 - 2020-03-04`, `2020-01-20 - 2020-03-04`?

Comment: Is `start_date` and `end_date` datetime? Or is it string.

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner By the above data if user user enters `2017-04-01` to `2017-04-08` , so the above r4ecord from `tableA` should return.

Comment: @ M1K1O I forget to mention. Its `date` format

Comment: @Subburaj: You haven't answered my question. I haven't aked what would happen did the user enter `2017-04-01` to `2017-04-08`. I gave another sample date range along with four ranges that you may consider a match for it or not. Please read my question again and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for an expression that checks for date range overlaps. Consider:

```
where start_date <= '2017-04-07' and end_date >= '2017-04-01'
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But Your query won't return any data. `start_date <= '2017-04-07'` itself condition is failed so it wont return the above record.

Comment: @ Akina From the above query its stating that startDate from user is greater than endDate from user.

Answer (score 0):

> Your query won't return any data.

That's weird. Bearing in mind that April has 30 days, this works just fine for me...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(start_date DATE NOT NULL
,end_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2017-04-01','2017-04-30');

SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE start_date <= '2017-04-07'
   AND end_date >= '2017-04-01' ;

+------------+------------+
| start_date | end_date   |
+------------+------------+
| 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-30 |
+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem a little confused about how to handle overlapping time frames (as well as the last day of April).

This logic:

```
WHERE start_date >= '2017-04-01' AND
      end_date <= '2017-04-07'
```

Is looking for `start_date`/`end_date` pairs that fall in the first week of April.

If you want *any* overlap, then you want the `start_date` to be before the end of the period and the `end_date` after the start:

```
WHERE start_date < '2017-04-07' AND
      end_date > '2017-04-01'
```

(If you include the endpoints, then you want `<=` and `>=`.)

If you want *complete* overlaps, then the start is one or before the first of April and the end is on or after a week later:

```
WHERE start_date <= '2017-04-01' AND
      end_date >= '2017-04-07'
```